# DatagramSocket: File sending, client does not receive image file

Tags: java, file, sockets, datagram

I am trying to send bunch of files with using DatagramSocket. But there is a problem which I can not figure out. Transferring files other than image files goes well but while sending image files, Client gets stuck at receive although Server send the file. Here is my client and server side code blocks:

Server:

```
    while (true) {
        System.out.print("DatagramSocket: Waiting for file request...\n");
        buf = new byte[Integer.SIZE];
        packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
        datagramSocket.receive(packet);
        bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(buf);

        // Receive request
        buf = new byte[bb.getInt()];
        packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
        datagramSocket.receive(packet);

        System.out.print("DatagramSocket: File request received.\n");
        System.out.print("DatagramSocket: Requested file: "+new String(buf)+"\n");

        // Check file if it is exist.
        File file = new File("kaynak/"+new String(buf));

        if (!file.exists()) {
            System.out.print("DatagramSocket: File not found!\n");
            return;
        }

        // Send file length.
        System.out.printf("DatagramSocket: Sending file length: %d\n", file.length());
        bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(Integer.SIZE).putInt((int) file.length());
        buf = bb.array();
        packet.setData(buf);
        packet.setLength(buf.length);
        datagramSocket.send(packet);

        // Send file's relative path.
        String relativePath = file.getAbsolutePath().substring(System.getProperty("user.dir").length() + 1);
        System.out.printf("DatagramSocket: Sending file relative path: %s\n", relativePath);
        bb.putInt(relativePath.getBytes().length);
        datagramSocket.send(packet);
        packet.setData(relativePath.getBytes());
        packet.setLength(relativePath.getBytes().length);
        datagramSocket.send(packet);

        // Save file to byte array.
        bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
        fileByteArray = new byte[(int) file.length()];
        bis.read(fileByteArray);

        System.out.printf("DatagramSocket: Sending file.\n");
        int r = (int) file.length();
        int c = 0;

        // Send file.
        for (int i = 0; i < file.length(); i++) {
            c = r < 512 ? r : 512;
            packet.setData(ByteBuffer.wrap(fileByteArray, i, c).array());
            packet.setLength(c);
            datagramSocket.send(packet);
            r -= 512;
            i += 511;
        }
        System.out.printf("DatagramSocket: File send.\n\n");
    }
```

Client:

```
// Send file request.
bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(Integer.SIZE).putInt(files.get(i).getBytes().length);
message = bb.array();
packet = new DatagramPacket(message, message.length, InetAddress.getByName(host), dport);
datagramSocket.send(packet);
message = files.get(i).getBytes();
System.out.print("Requesting: "+new String(message)+"\n");
packet.setData(message);
packet.setLength(message.length);
datagramSocket.send(packet);

// Receive file size.
System.out.print("Requesting file length.\n");
message = ByteBuffer.allocate(Integer.SIZE).array();
packet.setData(message);
packet.setLength(Integer.SIZE);
datagramSocket.receive(packet);
bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(message);
int arraySize = bb.getInt();
System.out.printf("File size = %d baytes.\n", arraySize);
fileByteArray = new byte[arraySize];

// Receive file's relative path.
System.out.print("Requesting file's relative path.\n");
datagramSocket.receive(packet);
message = ByteBuffer.allocate(message.length).array();
packet.setLength(message.length);
datagramSocket.receive(packet);
String htmlPath = new String(packet.getData());
System.out.printf("File's relative path = %s.\n", htmlPath);
File file = new File("hedef/"+htmlPath.substring("kaynak".length()));
file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
file.createNewFile();

// Receive file content.
System.out.print("Requesting file content.\n");
int r = arraySize;
int c = 0;

for (int j = 0; j < arraySize; j++) {
    c = r < 512 ? r : 512;
    packet.setData(ByteBuffer.wrap(fileByteArray, j, c).array());
    packet.setLength(c);
    datagramSocket.receive(packet);
    r -= 512;
    j += 511;
}

// Save file.
System.out.print("Saving file.\n");
bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
bos.write(fileByteArray);
bos.flush();
System.out.print("File saved.\n\n");
```

I also appreciate if can give me hints about my code, performance or wrong usage hints.
Thanks in advance.

**Update:**

After adding a little sleep time in for loop which sends file itself, now I am able to complete sending files but all images files I got is corrupted.

```
for (int j = 0; j < arraySize; j++) {
    c = r < 512 ? r : 512;
    packet.setData(ByteBuffer.wrap(fileByteArray, j, c).array());
    packet.setLength(c);
    datagramSocket.receive(packet);
    r -= 512;
    j += 511;
    Thread.sleep(50);
}
```

Comment: why do you use datagrams to send files? datagrams are not always reliable and there is no guarantee that the other side will get the data correctly.

Comment: It is a homework, I have to use Datagram :)
I know it is not reliable.

Comment: Were you able to send images successfully? If yes, I need help, how you are doing it?

Answer (score 2):

From DatagramSocket documentation: This method blocks until a datagram is received.
Obviously there are packages getting lost.

Also: It would be better to not allocate an array for the hole data to be received. Think of some 4GB video file... Instead allocate a buffer array the size of your read (512) and write it to your BufferedOutputStream immediately after DatagramSocket.receive().